# How to type an @ in iOS simulator using the hardware keyboard?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

While using the iOS Simulator it is no problem to type an @ symbole on the soft-keyboard.

However, when using the real keyboard (if connected using the simulator option `Hardware/Keyboard/Connect Hardware Keyboard`) pressing Option+L on the hardware keyboard does NOT type an **@** but **¬** sign...

This is quite annoying when testing login screens and other situations where an @ sign is needed. I have to bring up the soft keyboard first.

Is there any trick to use the hardware keyboard to type an @ sign in the iOS simulator?

BTW: I have no idea if this happens on real iOS devices with a real hardware keyboard as well, since I have no keyboard I could connect to a real iOS devices.

However this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's your keyboard layout. Option + L renders ¬ on both macOS and iOS for me. If you have an American English keyboard layout you probably want Shift + 2. If you prefer to use the keyboard layout you're accustomed to you might need to configure it in the simulator.

Comment: I am using a German keyboard layout and the option `Hardware/Keyboard/Use same Keyboard Languange as on macOS` is activated in the simulator. However it seems that still the American layout is used. So Shift + 2 works and the question is not "How to type an @" anymore but how to change the keyboard language in simulator :-) Thank you very much!